# Solar charge controller

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charging, charge, controller

I have a question related to pwm charge controller .If I have 120W,22V PV pannel and i have to charge a 12.8V ,54Ah battery,which solar controller to use, pwm or MPPT?

Comment: Either, provided they are compatible with your panel and battery.

Comment: Can pwm solar controller use buck boost or buck boost technique

Comment: Of course. But almost all commercial ones don't.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how will pwm solar charge controller use buck or boost technology

Comment: They are almost all just buck converters. There is nothing difficult about using boost or buck-boost but I have seen very few that actually do.